# Redux-Form: set shouldValidate to `() => true`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, react-redux, redux-form

Why don't I want to set `shouldValidate` to `() => True` in my form setup? In my browsing, I haven't seen anyone ever use it. It makes my validation work the way I want it to, where other combinations of `defaultShouldValidate()` and some of the other properties fed to the function have let to a few issues, as I have some dynamic error messages.

Here's a relevant snippet:

```
...
<myComponent Definition>
...

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(
    reduxForm({
        form: "<formName>",
        ... ,
        shouldValidate: () => true
    })(myComponent)
)
```

My initial testing while monitoring the CPU usage hasn't thrown any red flags, but something about this doesn't smell right to me. Is this a bad idea? Am I setting myself up with a time bomb? Why isn't this just the default?

Comment: If you are trying to store a reference to a function on `shouldValidate` prop then there is nothing wrong, but if you are trying to set true to the property instead you are doing it wrong

Comment: Right, that's what I'm doing (function reference, that is.) My concern is that there might be some performance hit if the validations run *too* frequently.

Comment: this seems to be the pattern, I call `validate()` in each `onChange`, if you are keeping your logic narrow I can't see how it's going to cause performance issues

Comment: On my form I'm typically validating ~20 fields at a time, each with a fairly short validator. Mostly simple regex and comparisons to `undefined`

Comment: There is no problem at all, this is how it should happen